# Dataframe implicitly holding a hierarchy to JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas

Say I have a dataframe like the following:

```
A    B   C       D
bar  X   one     1
bar  X   two     2
foo  Z   one     1
foo  Z   two     2
foo  Z   three   3
foo  Z   four    4
```

I would like to convert this to a JSON file as:

```
[{'A': 'bar',
  'B': 'X'
  'C': ['one', 'two']
  'D': ['1', '2']

 {'A': 'foo',
  'B': 'Z',
  'C': ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'}
  'D': ['1', '2', '3', '4'}
]
```

Certainly `df.to_json(orient='records')` didn't work. Is there any way to do this with `to_json`? Alternatively, how can I do this?

**Note:** In case there is ambiguity, the assumptions are simple: For each value of `A` there is only one value of `B`. Such pair correspond to a "record" that holds sequences of `C` and `D`, where for each value of `C` there is also only one value of `D`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B'])\
  .agg(tuple)\
  .reset_index()\
  .to_json(orient='records')
```

The trick here is to convert to tuples in the aggregation step instead of directly going for a list (somehow pandas [restricts this](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/groupby.py#L1609)). Tuples get json-serialized the same way as lists.